# Centrally aligning image in jquery cycle

Tags: jquery-cycle, alignment

I am using a jquery cycle to flip through some images but the images are aligned left instead of in the center of the div.  However, the images are centrally aligned once the jquery code is removed, I just don't know which part of the jquery code is forcing it left? See http://jsfiddle.net/ZdLDD/4/ for demo

I would like the image in the middle of the green box so the space on the left and right is even

```
<div id="samples">
                <ul id="sssnav">
                  <li id="sprev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
                  <li id="snext"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
                </ul>

                <ul id="sslides">
                  <li><img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/33wl55t.jpg" alt="" /><div id="samplestext">text</div></li>
                  <li><img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/33wl55t.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```